# How to use Data in multiple Activities in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-data

im working on my first project in Android Studio & I wonder how to use data from a User Input in another Activity (that is not the following Activity)

```
 ItemAdapter.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(position: Int, item: EmpUserClass) {
                val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, OverviewActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(USER_DETAILS, item)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
```

works fine on the next Activity. How can i manage it on following Activities?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers to your question:

- If the user only needs to be persisted for the current session (while the app is running), the better solution would be to put it in a singleton class that you'll use throughout your app (something like a `UserManager` class for instance)
- If this data needs to be persisted between launches (if you want the user to stay connected when restarting the app, for instance), you should use either [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), depending on the complexity of your data

Comment: or, probably the more official way, is to just make use of single activity architecture

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Actually i m using an SQLite Database, as i have to hold the Users. I m getting errors when i want to use data in further Activties.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create some kind of cache that would be Singleton and store the data there, and at the end use it when you need it.